# PHP: How to check for response code?

Tags: php, paypal, header, response, paypal-ipn

I'm a relative PHP newbie implementing a PayPal IPN listener and all seems to be working fine, except I dont really know how to check for a response code.

I've tried something ugly with cURL but it doesn't work at all (I'm not understanding cURL).

I've tried this piece of code that I grabbed from somewhere on the net:

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$response_headers = get_headers($fp);
$response_code = (int)substr($response_headers[0], 9, 3);
```

... but it's not working (returns $response_code = 0).

So right now, I'm debugging my IPN code without checking for a Response 200.

Can anyone more experienced advise me on what's the proper/simple way to check this?

Thanks

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what your get_headers() function does.

Comment: It's not mine :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: If you're using fsockopen, you must handle the entire http request yourself, Your above code just opens a socket, no http there.. thus, the call to get_headers doesn't make any sense at all. Look at Example #1 in the fsockopen documentation. Where are you stuck with cURL?

Comment: @zedoo: I see, thanks... with cURL, I understand that I can get the code with CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, but I don't quite understand what to initialise / what to pass to it from that PayPal request. Surely the response code must relate to that specific request and not a new one... I've tried using that $fp in it in various ways but I'm just not doing it right.

Comment: What zedoo is saying is that you've opened a socket but you haven't actually made a request, which of course means you will not receive a response header. =)

You might find some info here: http://www.scriptol.com/how-to/http-status-code-in-php.php

Comment: @Rob: Ah, that looks helpful. I'll give it a try, thanks. There is a fgets() call lower down in the paypal code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's get_headers(**$url**), not get_headers($fp).  Unless i'm reading it totally wrong (and there's some other mode i've never seen), you need to pass it the URL you're reading from, not a socket handle.  Actually, it apparently does its own GET, so it'd be useless for your current task.

fsockopen(...) is a lower level (TCP/IP) function.   It returns a socket handle, not a CURL handle.  Which is why you can't use curl_getinfo(...) on it.  You want something like this...

```
$fp = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($fp);

$response_code = curl_getinfo($fp, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

except as i remember, you need to add 'cmd=_notify-validate' to the post fields.

Don't use fsockopen(...).  Yeah, i know, that's what the Paypal sample code does.  But it's meant to run everywhere, and can't rely on CURL being installed.  You can, so use it.

Comment: Tested & works: $_POST should be replaced with $req (from the ready PayPal code so it contains all needed params), + curl_close($fp); at the end.